# cordova not defined even on device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get a custom plugin work but even without this custom plugin, when I try to use cordova.plugins, it throws this error in the browser, emulator, and real device.

[image]
Here's the code home.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
declare var cordova:any;
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {this.test();});
    }
    test() {
        console.log('platform is ready..');alert(typeof cordova);
    }
}
```

IONIC INFO:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.9.4
npm   : 5.6.0 
OS    : macOS High Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure cordova.js is added in your index.html

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, **I found the solution.**

The livereload plugin fails to serve cordova.js file and serves mock cordova file during development.

To fix this, open node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/dev-server/serve-config.js

and replace

```
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'android', 'assets', 'www');
```

to

```
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'android', 'app', 'src', 'main', 'assets', 'www');
```

and cordova is loaded and you can use the custom plugin code in your app.

Hope this will help others facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error means your path to your Cordova is invalid,

What I suggest is uninstall all Cordova versions and reinstall and use only that 1 because I had a similar problem.

Comment: $ which cordova
/usr/local/bin/cordova

I am using Mac and here's cordova. Isn't that right? And the version I have is 8.0.0.

Comment: Did you install it with brew?

Comment: no npm -g. but node and npm are installed via brew.

Comment: Not sure man, you need to make sure they are all talking to the same cordova file otherwise you get this error

Comment: Try your app on another working mac and it will probably work

Comment: Same on MacBook Pro as well :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused because I moved from:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

to

```
ionic build
cordova build android
```

once I moved back to ionic `cordova build android`, cordova var got defined again.